# ActiveAndroid - how to get last row id?

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I need to get last inserted row's id in ActiveAndroid database table and I can't find any information about that in documentation. Is there proper method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Get last record of the table and then pick auto-generated id something like this...

```
Model model = new Select().from(Model.class).orderBy("id DESC").executeSingle();
long id = (model != null) ? model.getId() : 0;
```

Here I've checked for **Null** because if table is empty it may be null.

Or hit this as following...

```
long id = new Select().from(Model.class).orderBy("id DESC").executeSingle().getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is an sqlite database and you can query this table you can use a sql function in your query:

***last_insert_rowid()***    The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function. ...

documentation taken from: 
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

```
int insert_id;

User user = new User();
user.name = "Louis";
user.password = 12345;
user.save();

insert_id = user.getId().intValue();
```

Hope this can help you!